# Gradle build is failing due to 'ProjectConfigurationException'

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to add few plugin,dependency and task in build.gradle but the gradle Sync is failing at very initial step on just adding one Plugin(google protobuf) with below error message . I have verified the settings.gradle have belowroot project Name.

```
rootProject.name = 'TestGRPC'
```

I have invalidated the cache of intellij and checked with other version of google protobuf but seeing same issue.
Can anyone unblock here?
[image]

Comment: Does it work fine from command line outside IDE?